# HTML5 localStorage usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a HUGE form that I intend for Quality Assurance personnel to use OFFLINE in the collection of data for Annual Product Quality Reviews. Because of the complexity of the regulatory requirements this form contains over 1900 fields and radio-buttons.

I have currently invoke localStorage via sisyphus.js and it's working - saving the data for all fields just fine.

My problem is that in loading it takes 7 seconds for the form to finish loading - granted it's a long time - but that's not the real issue. My REAL problem is that after making any entry it takes a little over 2 seconds after the onblur event for the form to accept any more input.

Here is my code:

```
$('form').sisyphus({
    locationBased: false,
    timeout: 10,
    autoRelease: false
});
```

My question: is there a way to invoke the storage of data at the discretion of the user, perhaps by a button, or some other method, in order to prevent the constant interruptions in data entry?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would have a look through the javascript debugger to find out what in the javascript is taking so long to process. Perhaps `sisyphus` loops through each element to save the entire form instead of just the one element. At this level, you need to look for any and all optimizations.

Comment: maybe split into multiple smaller forms?

Comment: @FrankerZ - I'll look into it, but my question is really one of functionality. Is it POSSIBLE to call the localStorage intermittently instead of persistently, which appears to be the case in all of the localStorage javaScript plugins that I've found.

Comment: @Markasoftware - hmmm... your comment has me investigating a different path now. I had placed my entire HTML document in ONE form element - and there's nothing that says I cannot break it up into different ones. I'll definitely test out the possibility of using MULTIPLE <form id="x"> elements within the one HTML document!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you're using (sisyphus.js) doesn't seem to have been written for handling a "large" amount of fields.

If you look at the source:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simsalabim/sisyphus/master/sisyphus.js

You'll see there's a method `saveAllData`. Coupled with the `bindSaveDataOnChange` method, it's saving all fields every time a field is changed.

And, if that wasn't the case, you'd still get the 2 second lag every 10 seconds (timeout option).

A quick fix, I'd hope, would be to fork/modify or override the plugin to null out the `bindSaveDataOnChange` method, and implement a hook for saving the form data on button click. And, perhaps, removing or increasing the `timeout` option.

Comment: OK - you get acknowledgement for being fast-in-the-trigger with a very complete answer to my question. Thanks for pointing me to the place in sisyphus.js that will give me what I need.